# Implement criterion for parameters to be optimized over in optim()

Tags: r, optimization, conditional-statements

I want to minimize a metric `d` that includes [GEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution)-distributed values.
Thus, I need to find `a, b` and `c` with `optim()`, such that `d` ideally converges to 0.

Here is a simplified excerpt from my code:

```
loc <- 3; sca <- 1; xi <- 0.1; o <- 1

gev.score <- function(pars,loc,sca,xi,o){
  # Parameters I want to find
  a <- pars[1]
  b <- pars[2]
  c <- pars[3]

  # Define d, that I want to minimize
  z   <- (o-(a+b*loc))/(c*sca)
  GEV <- exp(-(1+xi*z)^(-1/xi))
  d   <- 1-2*GEV
}

# Init values for a, b and c
init <- c(1,1,1)

# Let's optimize!
parameter <- optim(init,gev.score,
                   method='Nelder-Mead',
                   loc=loc,sca=sca,xi=xi,o=o,
                   control=list(maxit=40000))
```

However, the GEV is only defined for `-(1+xi*z) > 0`. Is it possible to implement this condition within `optim()`, such that it will only look out for combinations of `a, b` and `c` that fulfill this criterion?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement such a constraint is to have `gev.score` return a large number whenever the constraint is not met. You minimize, and so the algorithm will move away from points that violate the constraint.  (The downside of the approach is that you introduce jumps into the objective function, and this may create new troubles.)

With only three parameters to optimize, you might also consider a grid search.

By the way, it would help if you created a small reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so smart. I implemented your first suggestion and it is working (so far). I will also check your tip about the grid search.